# GDB is very slow with a multiple-thread program

Tags: multithreading, performance, gdb

**Well, i solved my problem with segmentation fault without gdb. So i don't need to solve the problem with slow performance anymore.
Thanks to all who tried to help.**

I'm trying to change a serial program to a parallel one. For it i'm using multiple threads.
My piece of code is called many times. And each time it creates 3 threads (joinable) and later i use "pthread_join" in each one. 
 
But when i run the code, it gives segmentation fault (5 sec to give segfault). So i try to debug it with gdb to see where is the problem. But when i run it with GDB, it is very slow (very very slow), and the gdb doesn't reach the segfault. 
P.s.: As the program progresses, gdb is getting slower. I suspect that "traces" of the threads  are left behind. pthread_join really clean the mess of the threads?

Comment: Configure your shell (with `ulimit -c` builtin of `bash`) so that a `core` file is dumped on `SIGSEGV`. Compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g`. Run it, it should dump a `core` file on `SIGSEGV`. Examine that file with `gdb yourprogram core`

Comment: The program is in C++, i'm just changing it, i didn't make it from the beginning. I looked in the Makefile and it uses g++ -Wall -g3 -gdwarf-2 -O0 -fmessage-length=0.